# Smoothing of Sequences

Tags: algorithm

I think there should be an algorithm for this out there - probably in a field like bioinformatics (the problem reminds me a bit of sequence alignment) so I hope someone can help me out here.

The problem is as follows: Assume I have classified some data into two different classes X and Y. The result of this may look something like this: ..XXX Y XXX.. Further assume that we have some domain knowledge about those classes and know that it's extremely unlikely to have less than a certain number of instances in a row (ie it's unlikely that there are less than 4 Xs or Ys in a sequence - preferably I could use a different threshold per class but that's not a must). So if we use this domain knowledge it's "obvious" that we'd like to replace the single Y in the middle with a X.

So the algorithm should take a sequence of classified instances and the thresholds for the classes (or 1 threshold for all if it simplifies the problem) and try to find a sequence that fulfills the property (no sequences of classes shorter than the given threshold). Obviously there can be an extremely large number of correct solutions (eg in the above example we could also replace all X with a Y) so I think a reasonable optimization criterium would be to minimize the number of replacements.

I don't need an especially efficient algorithm here since the number of instances will be rather small (say < 4k) and we'll only have two classes. Also since this is obviously only a heuristic I'm fine with some inaccuracies if they vastly simplify the algorithm.

Comment: Use erode operator with a custom filter kernel.

Comment: @ypnos I've read some short explanation of erosion (here)[http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/erode.htm] and don't see how I'd apply this here. Especially since I don't want to get rid of exterior classes if they're part of a block that is large enough. ie YYYY XXXXX (say with a threshold of 4 for both) shouldn't change. Maybe I misunderstand you - could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Erosion goes hand in hand with Dilation. Look into Opening operation. You would probably want to apply these in a more custom fashion.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the Viterbi algorithm, a dynamic-programming approach to inferring the most-probable input according to a Markov model. It's possible both of the current answers could be described that way; I didn't read them carefully enough to tell. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic programming as in the following pseudocode sketch (for simplicity, this code assumes the threshold is 3 Xs or Ys in a row, rather than 4):

```
min_switch(s):
  n = len(s)
  optx = array(4, n, infinity) // initialize all values to infinity
  opty = array(4, n, infinity) // initialize all values to infinity
  if s[0] == 'X':
    optx[1][0] = 0
    opty[1][0] = 1
  else:
    optx[1][0] = 1
    opty[1][0] = 0
  for i in {1, n - 1}:
    x = s[i]
    if x == 'X':
      optx[1][i] = opty[3][i - 1]
      optx[2][i] = optx[1][i - 1]
      optx[3][i] = min(optx[2][i - 1], optx[3][i - 1])
      opty[1][i] = 1 + min(optx[1][i - 1], optx[2][i - 1], optx[3][i - 1])
      opty[2][i] = 1 + opty[1][i - 1]
      opty[3][i] = 1 + min(opty[2][i - 1], opty[3][i - 1])
    else:
      optx[1][i] = 1 + min(opty[1][i - 1], opty[2][i - 1], opty[3][i - 1])
      optx[2][i] = 1 + opty[1][i - 1]
      optx[3][i] = 1 + min(opty[2][i - 1], opty[3][i - 1])
      opty[1][i] = optx[3][i - 1]
      opty[2][i] = opty[1][i - 1]
      opty[3][i] = min(opty[2][i - 1], opty[3][i - 1])
  return min(optx[3][n - 1], opty[3][n - 1])
```

The above code essentially computes the lowest cost of creating a smooth sequence up to the ith character storing the optimal value for all relevant numbers of consecutive Xs or Ys in a row (1, 2, or 3 in a row). More formally

- `opt[i][0][k]` stores the smallest
  cost to convert the string `s[0...k]`
  into a smooth sequence then ends in
  `i` consecutive Xs. Runs of 3 or more
  are accounted for in `opt[3][0][k]`.
- `opt[0][j][k]` stores the smallest
  cost to convert the string `s[0...k]`
  into a smooth sequence then ends in
  `j` consecutive Ys. Runs of 3 or more
  are accounted for in `opt[0][3][k]`.

It is straightforward to convert this to an algorithm that returns the sequence as well as the optimal cost.

Note that some of the cases in the above code are probably unnecessary, it's just a straightforward recurrence derived from the constraints.

Comment: Ok I've tried to understand the code, but I'm still not completely sure how the code works - so it's absolutely not straightforward for me ;) Could you explain what exactly we store in each columns of the multidimensional array?

Comment: I added some clarification regarding what `opt[i][j][k]` represents. Let me know if it still is not clear.

Comment: @jonderry Thanks - yes that made it much clearer. Personally I think using two arrays may have been easier though. The only "problem" (well it's undefined in the description really) I see is that the method has problems with the first 3 letters (violates the invariants) - but I'd say that's easily fixed by setting the first 3 chars according to majority vote (ie if 2 X and 1 Y set the Y to an X) and start only with the 4th one (obviously altering the start values in the arrays accordingly).

Comment: Yes, two arrays is more logical (will edit). Also, if memory use were an issue, you only need to store the information from the previous iteration. I don't think there's an issue with the first three characters. The `s[0]` step above should handle it correctly.

Comment: Also, I just edited the return value to ensure that we require 3 consecutive trailing Xs or Ys at the end of the smoothed string.

Answer (score 2):

A very similar problem to this can be solved as a classic dynamic programming shortest path problem. We wish to find the sequence which minimises some notion of cost. Penalise each character in the sequence that is different from the corresponding character in the original sequence. Penalise each change of character in the sequence, so penalise each change from X to Y and vice versa.

This is not quite what you want because the penalty for YYYXYYY is the same as the penalty for YXXXXXXY - one penalty for YX and one for XY - however it may be a good approximation because e.g. if the base sequence says YYY....YXY....YY then it will be cheaper to change the central X to a Y than to pay the cost of XY and YX - and you can obviously fiddle with the different cost penalties to get something that looks plausible.

Now think of each position in the sequence as being two points, one above the other, one point representing "X goes here" and one representing "Y goes here". You can link points with lines of cost depending on whether the corresponding character is X or Y in the original sequence, and whether the line joins an X with an X or an X with a Y or so on. Then work out the shortest path from left to right using a dynamic program that works out the best paths terminating in X and Y at position i+1, given knowledge of the cost of the best paths terminating in X and Y at position i.

If you really want to penalise short lived changes more harshly than long lived changes you can probably do so by increasing the number of points in the path-finding representation - you would have points that correspond to "X here and the most recent Y was 3 characters ago". But depending on what you want for a penalty you might end up with an incoveniently large number of points at each character.

Comment: Interesting idea. So I was kinda right with thinking about the sequence alignment problem - sounds a bit (well a small bit) similar. I should really look a bit more into dynamic programming - and implementing this sounds like a good way to do exactly that. Since at the moment my thresholds will be small enough this should work nicely with some useful cost function and the additional points. Not perfect, but then the naive solution would mean checking all permutations of the too short sequences which is non feasible.